# Xcode simulator does not show the new "News" app

Tags: xcode, simulator

I am taking a course on Coursera, which started from building a blank page. On the video lecture, when the lecturer runs the simulator and returns to the home page, there is the new iOS 9.0 "News" app, but I don't see it on my simulator.

I am wondering if it is a minor setting that I missed? It confuses me how such a new app shows up in a previously recorded video lecture but not my simulator.

Comment: You probably just need to download the latest simulator that has iOS 9.0

Comment: What region are you in? What region was the video recorded in? The news app is not available in all regions yet.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The video and I are both in the US. My simulator shows it's iOS 9.0